# How can I know the relation of Scheduled Jobs and DTS

Tags: sql-server-2000

I am using SQL Server 2000. How can I know which DTS has scheduled and the scheduled jobs is pointed to which DTS easily?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using SQL Server 2000. How can I know which DTS has scheduled and the scheduled jobs is pointed to which DTS easily?

That's not supported.

However, you can see scheduled linked and the jobs from DTS isn't scheduled in which database that are stored with. When R:Base stores permanently if it's rescheduled (with SP3), but might require administrative rights. So try that.